# How to delete files with wild card in Inno Script Studio?

Tags: file, inno-setup, wildcard

I am trying to delete some files during software update and cannot find a way to delete multiple files by using a wildcard.

I know that `DeleteFile()` deletes a single file, but if i need to delete a lot of files that have something in common, how can I do that with Inno Setup?

I cannot do this in `[InstallDelete]` section, because I have to make sure this is done when version constrains are met.

Comment: It is possible to conditionally process `[InstallDelete]` section entries if you add a [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) to their entries. Isn't that what you're missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @TLama, but I think I will do it differently.

Its is a lot easier to execute command line:

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/c del yourStringName.*',     
     location, SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ExecNumber);
```

If you want to avoid cmd, then @TLama pointed out a function that does that:

```
// Delete files matching C:\Test\*.tmp
DelTree('C:\Test\*.tmp', False, True, False);
```

Comment: I would point you to the [`DelTree`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_deltree) function if you answered me *no* to my comment (don't be confused by its name, it can delete only files and it supports wildcards in that case). Try to avoid using cmd as much as you can.

Comment: Thanks, the name was really confusing. And that function was something I was looking for. In your first comment you did not point out it and I though that `[InstallDelete]` is the only way. Anyways, tnx and I added that function to the answer to make it more clear

Comment: Well, I would personally show that command line way as a curiosity written with a very small font. As first I would prefer `Check` in the `[InstallDelete]` section (hence my initial comment), as next the `DelTree` function from code. And if neither of these exist, a command line. But thanks for the fix anyway, +1.